# cant download data for stock tickers like AA.A with dot in middle, yfinance

Tags: python, finance, yfinance

I have the following attempt to find a real stock that is listed on a website that catalogs all the stocks in the world:

```
import yfinance

yahoo_stock_obj = yfinance.Ticker('ADR.S'.upper())
# yahoo_stock_obj = yfinance.Ticker('ADR/S'.upper())

info = yahoo_stock_obj.get_info()

import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

This search does not bear fruit:

```
- ADR.S: No data found, symbol may be delisted
- ADR.S: No data found, symbol may be delisted
ipdb> yahoo_stock_obj.dividends
- ADR.S: No data found, symbol may be delisted
[]
ipdb> yahoo_stock_obj = yfinance.Ticker('ADR/S'.upper())
- ADR/S: No data found for this date range, symbol may be delisted
ipdb> yahoo_stock_obj.dividends
- ADR/S: No data found for this date range, symbol may be delisted
[]
```

The company is listed as "Ault Disruptive Technologies Corp" on the american stock exchange.

https://eoddata.com/stockquote/AMEX/ADR.S.htm

I want to get this data from yfinance the best stock api

Comment: A quick search on Yahoo Finance shows that `"ADRT"` is the ticker for this company on their platform: https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/ADRT?p=ADRT&.tsrc=fin-srch

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I have to know how to load all 10000 stocks on the US markets. How do I know when to ignore the ADRT.T (.T portion)? Do I always cut off the right side from the dot forward? Thank you